# Intellij IDEA signing GIT commits with GPG

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gpg-signature

GPG signing of GIT commits works in terminal but not in Intellij Idea.

```
gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have working GPG signing of your GIT commits in terminal but not in Intellij Idea you can use `pinentry-mac`. Don't forget to update your `gpg.conf` and `gpg-agent.conf` files as well.

```
brew install pinentry-mac
echo "no-tty" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
echo $(which pinentry-mac) >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
```

More information here: https://nathanielhoag.com/blog/2016/09/05/signing-commits-in-git/